# How to extract string from Pandas Series using Regex that begins with any uppercase letter

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract a string Series into a new Series that contains only strings started with uppercase letter of the original Series data.

I have tried using regex in a pandas series before and it worked well so I use it as reference. Code below is what I used in my current issue.

```
harness['new'] = harness['Material'].str.extract('.*\-(.*)\-.*',expand=True)
```

Below code is what I currently use in order to extract strings started with uppercase letter

```
In [63]:
batch1['Wire Name'].head()

Out[63]:
0    2HC31A20
1    HC30A20
2    2HC42A20
3    2HC5H20
4    HC4M20

In [64]:
batch1['Grouping'] = batch1['Wire Name'].str.extract('^[A-Z].*',expand=True)
batch1['Grouping'].head()

Out [64]:
ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups
```

I expect the result to be:

```
0    HC31A20
1    HC30A20
2    HC42A20
3     HC5H20
4     HC4M20
```

What do you think is wrong? I have checked from the regex page and examples of using it but thet didn't work when I use above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['2HC31A20', 'HC30A20', '2HC42A20','2HC5H20', 'HC4M20']})
df['text'].str.extract(r'(^[A-Z][\w]+)', expand=False)

0        NaN
1    HC30A20
2        NaN
3        NaN
4     HC4M20
```

**Description:**

`^[A-Z]` : This means to start with capitals letters only. 
`[\w]+` : This means to take all the `A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _` after the capital letters.

Comment: What does the 'r' mean before the regex code? In my case I want to filter 0,2,3  not to make them null

Comment: Thanks heena I just realized by your response thati need to add parenthesis between the main regex code and now it works

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression should be " **[A-Z].*** ". **^** will try to match from the start of the string.

Comment: Does this actually work? I think it still throws a `ValueError`.

Comment: This regex works by adding parenthesis between the regex. Thanks raka

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can simply use a `[A-Z]` as a left boundary, then swipe to right and collect the rest of string, maybe similar to:

```
(.+?)([A-Z].+)
```

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(.+?)([A-Z].+)"

test_str = ("0    2HC31A20\n"
    "1    HC30A20\n"
    "2    2HC42A20\n"
    "3    2HC5H20\n"
    "4    HC4M20\n")

subst = "\\2"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/09QJ0n/1/).

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /(.+?)([A-Z].+)/gm;
const str = `0    2HC31A20
1    HC30A20
2    2HC42A20
3    2HC5H20
4    HC4M20
`;
const subst = `$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: A javascript demo is not particularly helpful for a python question. Just FYI. There is such a thing as overkill when answering a question this simple ;-)

Comment: I should also mention that this is a pandas question so your python code is not helpful either. :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks my code works by adding parentheses between the main regex

```
In[63]:
batch1['Wire Name'].head()

Out[63]:
0    2HC31A20
1    HC30A20
2    2HC42A20
3     2HC5H20
4     HC4M20
Name: Wire Name, dtype: object


In [147]:
batch1['Grouping'] = batch1['Wire Name'].str.extract('([A-Z].*)',expand=True)
batch1['Grouping'].head()

Out[147]:
0    HC31A20
1    HC30A20
2    HC42A20
3     HC5H20
4     HC4M20
Name: Grouping, dtype: object
```

Im not sure why though I thought parentheses is used to choose in which part of the regex we want to extract?

Isn't without parentheses it will result the same stuff?